# How to convert the data type of one column in DolphinDB table?

Tags: database, time-series, dolphindb

The schema of table in DolphinDB is as below.

```
partitionColumnIndex->-1
chunkPath->
colDefs->
name      typeString typeInt comment
--------- ---------- ------- -------
timestamp SECOND     10             
sym       STRING     18             
qty       INT        4              
price     DOUBLE     16
```

I would like to convert the data type of column sym from STRING to SYMBOL ,since the manual mentioned that datatype SYMBOL can improve the performance of query.

I have tried the following script.

```
update t set sym=symbol(sym)
```

But the schema of table did not change.

Answer (score 1):

sql update can update the content of a column, but can't change the data type. If you would like to change both type and content, please use function replaceColumn!, which is available since version 0.99

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `char` and `varchar` types of length less than or equal to 10 will be converted to `SYMBOL` type in DolphinDB. That's why `SYMBOL` improves the performance of a query, since it takes less overhead. String types of length greater than 10 will be converted to `STRING` type in DolphinDB. Therefore, these two data types are two separate entities and CANNOT be converted between each other or have their scopes redefined, as DolphinDB renders each data type based on its length by default.